# Android ListView row view with left and right border stretched to height

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an Android ListView which I want to have contain rows with a single `TextView` with text (`titleTextView`), and which I want to have a left (`leftCellBorder`) and right (`rightCellBorder`) border image which is stretched to fill the height of the row.

The height of the row depends on how much text there is in `titleTextView`. If the text spills onto a second line, then the two borders should be vertically stretched to fill the height of the border.

So with a single line of text, the row view should look like this:

[image]

With two lines of text, the row view should look this:

[image]

The first version of my XML went like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/leftCellBorder"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/cell_border_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightCellBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cell_border_right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought that having the `leftCellBorder` and `rightCellBorder`'s `layout_height` as `match_parent` would be enough to ensure they were stretched to be the correct height, but this didn't work and the result I got was as follows:

[image]

i.e. the images are not being stretched to fill the height.

So then I went back and tried to use a horizontal `LinearLayout` at the root instead of `RelativeLayout` and had 3 child views. This actually worked, and the left and right borders were properly stretched to fill the height, but then the problem I've had is that there doesn't seem to be a way of clamping the `rightCellBorder` to the right hand side with a `LinearLayout` (unless I'm missing something).

So -- how can I achieve the effect I'm looking for? Preferably I would like to stick with `RelativeLayout` since that gives me more flexibility. Surely this shouldn't be so difficult!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear layout is definitely a better layout choice for you design (and its quicker to render). You just need to make use of the layout_weight property.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftCellBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cell_border_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp" <!-- When assigning a weight, either the width or the height will be inferred from the weight depending upon your layouts orientation. Whichever will be inferred should be set to 0dp, it's more efficient. -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" <!-- If only one child has weight, it occupies all the remaining space. (As with real children.) -->
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consecteteur Adipiscing Elit"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightCellBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cell_border_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: 
The easiest solution however, would be to create a 9-patch for your background drawable, ditch the ImageViews and apply that to your TextView; you can simply use padding to make sure the text remains in the transparent portion... Like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" <!-- Use the padding to space the text from your sides -->
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/YOUR_9_PATCH"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consecteteur Adipiscing Elit"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can use the padding on the layout if you want/need space outside of the TextView but before surrounding elements...

Comment: This is actually a great answer, and I'm particularly a fan of your edit to use a 9patch instead. Because I want to apply some padding to my background in the final app, I've decided to put my 9patch into an `ImageView` and use that as the background view: `<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/cellBorder"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:background="@drawable/cell_border" />`
Only problem is that it's *still* not filling the `RelativeLayout` height!

Comment: Looks like a circular dependency which plagues `RelativeLayout`... The `match_parent` wants its height from the parent, but the parent is set to `wrap_content`, so there's a conflict. Guess I'll need to switch to `LinearLayout` after all!

Comment: @jon Yea, I find that my main purpose for RelativeLayouts is when I want elements non-linearly positioned. If I want them linearly positioned with relative size, then a LinearLayout is best. Also, you don't need to put your 9-patch in an ImageView, I'll put up layout code for that...

Comment: In the end, I just put my 9patch straight into the `android:background` attribute of my `RelativeLayout` and was done with it. Too much fiddling about. Ideally I wanted to apply some padding on the background and now I can't do that... but actually my view is a little more complex as I simplified for purposes of the question, and switching to a `LinearLayout` will just be too much work.

Comment: @jon Ahh... I was wondering why you didn't switch, the example layout was simple enough to easily redo from scratch... Well, as long as a solution worked, it's solid!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with a `RelativeLayout` change the attributes of the ImageViews to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/titleTextView"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleTextView"
```

and remove `alignParentTop`, `alignParentBottom`, and `layout_gravity`.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to LinearLayout and try:

```
<ImageView
.
.
android:layout_weight="0"
>
<TextView
.
.
android:layout_weight="1"
>
<ImageView
.
.
android:layout_weight="0"
>
```

(Make sure android:layout_width="wrap_content" on all the Views)